# Handling several warnings differently in for loop, tryCatch

Tags: r, event-handling

I am running a function in R across a dataset, within a for-loop.  It is a fisheries ecology function removal(), within the FSA package.  It takes a vector (ll), runs a model `removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5)`, and gives the output, which I store the relevant coefficients of in a separate results dataframe.  The issue arises when a warning occurs.  For example, if ll is not descending, a warning (we'll call it warning 1) is thrown.  If ll only has a number in the first spot of the vector, it throws a different warning (warning 2).  If sum(ll) = 1, then a different warning (warning 3) is thrown.  There are ways I would like to handle each of these warnings, i.e calculate the outputs for the results DF. I.e, a return of warning 1 would be `sum(ll)*1.5`, warning 2 would be `sum(ll)`,  etc.  I have constructed some rudimentary code that is effective at handling and patching the results DF together if one of two warnings

```
mod_resDF[j,4:6] <- 
    tryCatch(
      c(round(as.numeric(c(removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5)$est[c(1,2)])),3), 
        paste(removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5, CIMicroFish = T)$est[3],"-",
        removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5, CIMicroFish = T)$est[4], sep = "")),
    warning = \(w) {
      if(grepl("The Burnham method failed to find estimates", w$message)) {
        c(sum(ll)*1.5, 0, paste(sum(ll)*1.5,"-", sum(ll)*1.5, sep = ""))
      } else{
      c(as.numeric(c(removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5)$est[c(1,2)])), 
               paste(ifelse(removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5, CIMicroFish = T)$est[3] < sum(ll), sum(ll),removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5, CIMicroFish = T)$est[3]) ,"-",
                     removal(ll, method = "Burnham", Tmult = 5, CIMicroFish = T)$est[4], sep = ""))
        }
      }
    )
  mod_resDF[j,4] <- ifelse(is.na(mod_resDF[j,4]), sum(ll), mod_resDF[j,4])
  mod_resDF[j,5] <- ifelse(is.na(mod_resDF[j,5]), 0, mod_resDF[j,5])
  mod_resDF[j,6] <- ifelse(grepl("NA", mod_resDF[j,6]) == T, paste(sum(ll), "-", sum(ll), sep = ""), mod_resDF[j,6])
```

However, its in a quick and dirty stage at this point, and kicks out of the loop if the third warning is encountered.  Is there a way to explicitly write into the function what to do if each of the warnings is encountered?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at `purrr::quietly`. I find it easier to use than `tryCatch()` for handling warnings.

Comment: What is the "third warning" that causes the issue? (And is it actually a warning, or an error?)

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to respond conditionally to warnings like this, but if you're encountering problems it may be better to test for the conditions that trigger the warning and handle them before the warning is thrown (e.g., with early return of your desired value). LBYL instead of EAFP.

Comment: The third warning is if the sum of the vector ll is 1.  The output of that should be 1, along with some coefficients that will need to be manually entered.

Comment: That is a good point.  I will see if I can structure the code like that.  Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @GradStu I meant, what is the text of the warning.

Comment: Ah.   Here. "Total catch of one fish results in model failure for Burnham method. "